# Draw a path entirely contact operator

Tags: tikz-pgf

I just learn LaTeX and draw 2 matrices and want to connect their nodes in TikZ, but I cannot draw a path entirely contact with `\oplus` operator.

BTW, why I can't use `\boxplus` in Tikz while `\oplus` is fine? Thanks.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,positioning,shapes,arrows}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\size}{\linewidth}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    every path/.style={draw, font=\small},
    labelfield/.style={outer sep=0pt, minimum height=5mm,font=\small, anchor=center},
    field/.style={outer sep=0pt, draw, minimum height=8mm,
    minimum width=#1\size,font=\small,anchor=center}]

    \matrix (A) [matrix of nodes, column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
    row 1/.style={nodes={field=.1}}] {
     |[field=.1]|$R_1^{(t)}$ & |[field=.1]|$R_2^{(t)}$ & |[field=.1]|$R_3^{(t)}$ & |[field=.1]|$R_4^{(t)}$ & |[field=.1]|$R_5^{(t)}$ & |[field=.1]|$R_6^{(t)}$ & |[field=.1]|$R_7^{(t)}$ & |[field=.1]|$R_8^{(t)}$ \\
    };
    \matrix(B) [matrix of nodes, below=5mm of A-1-2.south east,  column sep=0.75cm] { $\oplus$ & $\oplus$ & $\oplus$ & $\oplus$\\ };
    \draw[->] (A-1-1) edge node {}(B-1-1);
    \draw node at (7,1)[field=.1] (i) {$<i>$};


\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like this?

[image]

to matrix B just add option `nodes={inner ysep=0pt},`:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,positioning,shapes,arrows}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\size}{\linewidth}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    every path/.style={draw, font=\small},
    labelfield/.style={outer sep=0pt, minimum height=5mm,font=\small, anchor=center},
    field/.style={outer sep=0pt, draw, minimum height=8mm,
    minimum width=#1\size,font=\small,anchor=center}]

    \matrix (A) [matrix of nodes, column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
    row 1/.style={nodes={field=.1}}] {
     |[field=.1]|$R_1^{(t)}$ & |[field=.1]|$R_2^{(t)}$ & |[field=.1]|$R_3^{(t)}$ & |[field=.1]|$R_4^{(t)}$ & |[field=.1]|$R_5^{(t)}$ & |[field=.1]|$R_6^{(t)}$ & |[field=.1]|$R_7^{(t)}$ & |[field=.1]|$R_8^{(t)}$ \\
    };
    \matrix(B) [matrix of nodes,
                nodes={inner ysep=0pt}, % <---- added
                column sep=0.75cm,
                below=5mm of A-1-2.south east]
    { $\oplus$ & $\oplus$ & $\oplus$ & $\oplus$\\ };
    \draw[->] (A-1-1) edge node {}(B-1-1);
    \draw node at (7,1)[field=.1] (i) {$<i>$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```